# Browse a directory and retrieve paths in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I did a function that scans my directory and I get the following results:

```
Array
(
    [2013\] => Array
        (
            [10\] => Array
                (
                    [30\] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file1.xml
                            [1] => file2.xml
                        )

                )

        )

    [2020\] => Array
        (
            [01\] => Array
                (
                    [01\] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file1.xml
                            [1] => file2.xml
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

I would like to find a solution to browse my tables to get paths to display my results as follows:

```
2013\10\30\file1.xml
2013\10\30\file2.xml
2020\01\01\file1.xml
2020\01\01\file2.xml
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try this. its modified from an example from php.net
http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#114504

```
$directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator('test');
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$files = array();
foreach ($iterator as $info) {
    if (in_array(basename($info->getPathname()), ['.', '..'])) {
        continue;
    }
    $files[] = $info->getPathname();
}

print_r($files);
```